# Capturing multi td elements in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am working on implementation of selecting cells in the table.

I found really good solution here:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [];
});

app.directive('dragSelect', function($window, $document) {
  return {
    scope: {
      dragSelectIds: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      var cls = 'eng-selected-item';
      var startCell = null;
      var dragging = false;

      function mouseUp(el) {
        dragging = false;
      }
      
      function mouseDown(el) {
        dragging = true;
        setStartCell(el);
        setEndCell(el);
      }
      
      function mouseEnter(el) {
        if (!dragging) return;
        setEndCell(el);
      }
      
      function setStartCell(el) {
        startCell = el;
      }
      
      function setEndCell(el) {
        $scope.dragSelectIds = [];
        $element.find('td').removeClass(cls);
        $(cellsBetween(startCell, el)).each(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          el.addClass(cls);
          $scope.dragSelectIds.push(el.attr('id'));
        });
      }
      
      function rectangleSelect(selector, x1,x2, y1, y2) {
    var elements = [];
    jQuery(selector).each(function() {
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        var offset = $this.offset();
        var x = offset.left;
        var y = offset.top;
        var w = $this.width();
        var h = $this.height();

        if (x >= x1 && x<=x2 && y>=y1 && y<=y2) {
            // this element fits inside the selection rectangle
            elements.push($this.get(0));
        }
    });
    return elements;
}
      
      function cellsBetween(start, end) {
        
        var bounds = {minX:0,minY:0,maxX:0,maxY:0};
        bounds.minX = $window.Math.min($(start).offset().left,$(end).offset().left);
        bounds.minY = $window.Math.min($(start).offset().top,$(end).offset().top);
        bounds.maxX = $window.Math.max($(end).offset().left+$(end).width(),$(start).offset().left+$(start).width());
        bounds.maxY = $window.Math.max($(end).offset().top+$(end).height(),$(start).offset().top+$(start).height());

        var initiallySelectedTds = rectangleSelect("td",bounds.minX,bounds.maxX,bounds.minY,bounds.maxY);
        
        for(var i=0;i<initiallySelectedTds.length;i++){
          if($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left<bounds.minX)
            bounds.minX = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left;
          if($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left+$(initiallySelectedTds[i]).width()>bounds.maxX)
            bounds.maxX = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left+$(initiallySelectedTds[i]).width();
          if($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top<bounds.minY)
            bounds.minY = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top;
          if($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top+$(initiallySelectedTds[i]).height()>bounds.maxY)
            bounds.maxY = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top+$(initiallySelectedTds[i]).height();
        }
        return rectangleSelect("td",bounds.minX,bounds.maxX,bounds.minY,bounds.maxY);
        
      }
      
    
      function wrap(fn) {
        return function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(el);
          });
        }
      }
      
      $element.delegate('td', 'mousedown', wrap(mouseDown));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseenter', wrap(mouseEnter));
      $document.delegate('body', 'mouseup', wrap(mouseUp));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
[drag-select] {
  cursor: pointer;
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
}

[drag-select] .eng-selected-item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table drag-select drag-select-ids="ids">
      <tr>
        <td id="td-1-1">1-1</td>
        <td id="td-1-2">1-2</td>
        <td id="td-1-3">1-3</td>
        <td id="td-1-4">1-4</td>
        <td id="td-1-5">1-5</td>
        <td id="td-1-6">1-6</td>
        <td id="td-1-7">1-7</td>
        <td id="td-1-8">1-8</td>
        <td id="td-1-9">1-9</td>
        <td id="td-1-10">1-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-2-1">2-1</td>
        <td id="td-2-2">2-2</td>
        <td id="td-2-3">2-3</td>
        <td id="td-2-4">2-4</td>
        <td id="td-2-5">2-5</td>
        <td id="td-2-6">2-6</td>
        <td id="td-2-7">2-7</td>
        <td id="td-2-8">2-8</td>
        <td id="td-2-9">2-9</td>
        <td id="td-2-10">2-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-3-1">3-1</td>
        <td id="td-3-2">3-2</td>
        <td id="td-3-3">3-3</td>
        <td id="td-3-4">3-4</td>
        <td id="td-3-5">3-5</td>
        <td id="td-3-6">3-6</td>
        <td id="td-3-7">3-7</td>
        <td id="td-3-8">3-8</td>
        <td id="td-3-9">3-9</td>
        <td id="td-3-10">3-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-4-1">4-1</td>
        <td id="td-4-2">4-2</td>
        <td id="td-4-3">4-3</td>
        <td id="td-4-4">4-4</td>
        <td id="td-4-5">4-5</td>
        <td id="td-4-6">4-6</td>
        <td id="td-4-7">4-7</td>
        <td id="td-4-8">4-8</td>
        <td id="td-4-9">4-9</td>
        <td id="td-4-10">4-10</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="td-5-1">5-1</td>
        <td id="td-5-2">5-2</td>
        <td id="td-5-3">5-3</td>
        <td id="td-5-4">5-4</td>
        <td id="td-5-5">5-5</td>
        <td id="td-5-6">5-6</td>
        <td id="td-5-7">5-7</td>
        <td id="td-5-8">5-8</td>
        <td id="td-5-9">5-9</td>
        <td id="td-5-10">5-10</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Selected IDs: {{ids | json}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

The cell selection works great. After the selection, I want to be able to select more cells, without the previous ones disappearing and also be able to deselect the already selected one.

Now basically every time I click into the table, previous selection disappears and the new one start.

Does anyone have any idea, how I could implement this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could detect the `ctrl-click`

Comment: I was trying to store the output in the variable, and than passing it to the function every time the mouse clicks, but with no success. I am new to JavaScript and cant really get my head around it..

Comment: The selection works with rectangles. What you could do: on `mouseDown`: if `ctrl` is down : create a new rectangle, else : clear all rectangles. You need an array to store all rectangles.

Comment: Provide the code you tried so far. Stackoverflow is here to help you, not to solve your problems. Show that you spent some time working on it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modify you `setEndCell function` like,

```
function mouseEnter(el) {
    if (!dragging) return;
    setEndCell(el);
  }


  function setEndCell(el) {
    if (el.hasClass(cls)) { // if added then remove on click
      el.removeClass(cls);
      var elIndex = $scope.dragSelectIds.indexOf(el[0].id);
      elIndex !==-1 && $scope.dragSelectIds.splice(elIndex, 1)
      return false;
    }
    if (!$scope.dragSelectIds) {
      $scope.dragSelectIds = [];
    }
    //$element.find('td').removeClass(cls);
    $(cellsBetween(startCell, el)).each(function() {
      var el = angular.element(this);
      el.addClass(cls);
      // change if added, then not to add twice.
      var elIndex = $scope.dragSelectIds.indexOf(el[0].id);
      elIndex ===-1 && $scope.dragSelectIds.push(el.attr('id'));
    });
  }
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [];
});

app.directive('dragSelect', function($window, $document) {
  return {
    scope: {
      dragSelectIds: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      var cls = 'eng-selected-item';
      var startCell = null;
      var dragging = false;

      function mouseUp(el) {
        dragging = false;
      }

      function mouseDown(el) {
        dragging = true;
        setStartCell(el);
        setEndCell(el);
      }

      function mouseEnter(el) {
        if (!dragging) return;
        setEndCell(el);
      }

      function setStartCell(el) {
        startCell = el;
      }

      function setEndCell(el) {
        if (el.hasClass(cls)) {
          el.removeClass(cls);
          var elIndex = $scope.dragSelectIds.indexOf(el[0].id);
          elIndex !==-1 && $scope.dragSelectIds.splice(elIndex, 1)
          return false;
        }
        if (!$scope.dragSelectIds) {
          $scope.dragSelectIds = [];
        }
        //$element.find('td').removeClass(cls);
        $(cellsBetween(startCell, el)).each(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          el.addClass(cls);
          var elIndex = $scope.dragSelectIds.indexOf(el[0].id);
          elIndex ===-1 && $scope.dragSelectIds.push(el.attr('id'));
        });
      }

      function rectangleSelect(selector, x1, x2, y1, y2) {
        var elements = [];
        jQuery(selector).each(function() {
          var $this = jQuery(this);
          var offset = $this.offset();
          var x = offset.left;
          var y = offset.top;
          var w = $this.width();
          var h = $this.height();

          if (x >= x1 && x <= x2 && y >= y1 && y <= y2) {
            // this element fits inside the selection rectangle
            elements.push($this.get(0));
          }
        });
        return elements;
      }

      function cellsBetween(start, end) {

        var bounds = {
          minX: 0,
          minY: 0,
          maxX: 0,
          maxY: 0
        };
        bounds.minX = $window.Math.min($(start).offset().left, $(end).offset().left);
        bounds.minY = $window.Math.min($(start).offset().top, $(end).offset().top);
        bounds.maxX = $window.Math.max($(end).offset().left + $(end).width(), $(start).offset().left + $(start).width());
        bounds.maxY = $window.Math.max($(end).offset().top + $(end).height(), $(start).offset().top + $(start).height());

        var initiallySelectedTds = rectangleSelect("td", bounds.minX, bounds.maxX, bounds.minY, bounds.maxY);

        for (var i = 0; i < initiallySelectedTds.length; i++) {
          if ($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left < bounds.minX)
            bounds.minX = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left;
          if ($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left + $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).width() > bounds.maxX)
            bounds.maxX = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().left + $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).width();
          if ($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top < bounds.minY)
            bounds.minY = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top;
          if ($(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top + $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).height() > bounds.maxY)
            bounds.maxY = $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).offset().top + $(initiallySelectedTds[i]).height();
        }
        return rectangleSelect("td", bounds.minX, bounds.maxX, bounds.minY, bounds.maxY);

      }


      function wrap(fn) {
        return function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(el);
          });
        }
      }

      $element.delegate('td', 'mousedown', wrap(mouseDown));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseenter', wrap(mouseEnter));
      $document.delegate('body', 'mouseup', wrap(mouseUp));
    }
  }
});
```

```css
[drag-select] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

[drag-select] .eng-selected-item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table drag-select drag-select-ids="ids">
    <tr>
      <td id="td-1-1">1-1</td>
      <td id="td-1-2">1-2</td>
      <td id="td-1-3">1-3</td>
      <td id="td-1-4">1-4</td>
      <td id="td-1-5">1-5</td>
      <td id="td-1-6">1-6</td>
      <td id="td-1-7">1-7</td>
      <td id="td-1-8">1-8</td>
      <td id="td-1-9">1-9</td>
      <td id="td-1-10">1-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td-2-1">2-1</td>
      <td id="td-2-2">2-2</td>
      <td id="td-2-3">2-3</td>
      <td id="td-2-4">2-4</td>
      <td id="td-2-5">2-5</td>
      <td id="td-2-6">2-6</td>
      <td id="td-2-7">2-7</td>
      <td id="td-2-8">2-8</td>
      <td id="td-2-9">2-9</td>
      <td id="td-2-10">2-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td-3-1">3-1</td>
      <td id="td-3-2">3-2</td>
      <td id="td-3-3">3-3</td>
      <td id="td-3-4">3-4</td>
      <td id="td-3-5">3-5</td>
      <td id="td-3-6">3-6</td>
      <td id="td-3-7">3-7</td>
      <td id="td-3-8">3-8</td>
      <td id="td-3-9">3-9</td>
      <td id="td-3-10">3-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td-4-1">4-1</td>
      <td id="td-4-2">4-2</td>
      <td id="td-4-3">4-3</td>
      <td id="td-4-4">4-4</td>
      <td id="td-4-5">4-5</td>
      <td id="td-4-6">4-6</td>
      <td id="td-4-7">4-7</td>
      <td id="td-4-8">4-8</td>
      <td id="td-4-9">4-9</td>
      <td id="td-4-10">4-10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="td-5-1">5-1</td>
      <td id="td-5-2">5-2</td>
      <td id="td-5-3">5-3</td>
      <td id="td-5-4">5-4</td>
      <td id="td-5-5">5-5</td>
      <td id="td-5-6">5-6</td>
      <td id="td-5-7">5-7</td>
      <td id="td-5-8">5-8</td>
      <td id="td-5-9">5-9</td>
      <td id="td-5-10">5-10</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Selected IDs: {{ids | json}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you know, how I would deselect the cells once clicked?

Comment: Now when you drag across items, all of the IDs are added every time (duplicating items in the output). I need to check somehow, if the ID is already in the array and if it is, do not add.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but now when I try to deselect multiple cells, it does not work and I need to click one by one. Any idea?

Comment: Use the code `function mouseEnter(el) {
        if (!dragging) return;
        setEndCell(el);
      }`

Comment: At the moment,if the cells are deselected, I create a "virtual" rectangle and selects all required cells.

I want the same thing for deselect, but it does not do it the "rectangle" way. Any idea what the problem may be?